# Swift 4: Click button to next View Controller but the new page's animation is "cover vertically" instead of "shifting" to next page

Tags: swift, swift4

I am newbie of Swift 4 and I am trying to simply click a button and go to next page.
So I add a button in the first page and another view controller. Then I drag the button to the next page to create the "transaction". However, the animation of the transaction to pop up the next page from bottom, as shown in the image below. What I expect is to shift horizontally from current page to next page. Where did I do wrong? How can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the first view controller and choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. Make sure your segue is Show (Push).

Comment: Thank you! And then I found the text on the top left corner in next page is "back". Can I change it to another text?

Comment: Yes but that is a different matter.